# What is relationship between FileShare enum and other FileStream constructors enums

Tags: c#, enums

I searched the answer to the question "What is default value of FileShare enum" and find the answer[IO.FileStream : FileShare default ?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/abfd5a1d-2dc1-438d-b280-4ea12b5908d5/iofilestream-fileshare-default-?prof=required). In this answer also is link to MSDN [FileStream Constructor (String, FileMode)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy.aspx). I understand from this answer, that in different FileStream constructors FileShare enum default value also can be different depending on other these constructors parameters. May be someone knows the logic of the relationship between  FileShare enum and other FileStream constructors enums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is very simple. If you supply a `FileShare` value it will use that, otherwise it will use `FileShare.Read`.

The documentation says:

> "FileShare.Read is the default for those FileStream constructors
>   without a FileShare parameter."

This means that all constructors without a `FileShare` parameter uses `FileShare.Read`, and all constructors that have a `FileShare` parameter will use that parameter value.